# MySQL refuses to sum data from session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have this code and it works perfectly well:

```
$res=mysql_query('SELECT ((SELECT SUM(mball_h) FROM pr) + (SELECT 
SUM(mball_i) FROM pr)) AS theSum'); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
```

then i echo with this

```
<?php echo $row['theSum']; ?>
```

Now, I want to do this:

```
SUM(mball_h) from pr WHERE mball_0 = $_SESSION['SESS_mball_0']
```

Here is the code that does not work"

```
$res=mysql_query('SELECT ((SELECT SUM(mball_h) FROM pr WHERE mball_0 = 
$_SESSION["SESS_mball_0"]) + (SELECT SUM(mball_i) FROM pr WHERE mball_0 = 
$_SESSION["SESS_mball_0"])) AS theSum');    
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: The session value probably needs to be quoted with `'`. That second bit isn't a complete SQL statement, though, so it's hard to tell much.

Comment: Providing the code that isn't working, along with the results you are receiving / error logs, will help the community to provide a solution.

Comment: Incidentally, you are using an outdated mysql extension and that code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @AnthonyL i just added the code.

Comment: now - with the new code - it's a different situation. Variables won't get parsed inside singe-quoted strings. So try `'SELECT ((SELECT ...WHERE mball_0 = '.$_SESSION["SESS_mball_0"]) .') + ...'`. For a starter.

Comment: But still you should change to either mysqli_* or PDO _and_ use prepared statements (which would have avoided that error).

Comment: There's no need for those nested selects. `SELECT SUM(mball_h + mball_i) FROM pr WHERE mball_0 = ..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are only expanded inside double-quoted strings, not single-quoted strings. See [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

And if the variable is an array with a quoted index, you need to wrap it in `{}`. So it should be:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT ((SELECT SUM(mball_h) FROM pr WHERE mball_0 = 
    {$_SESSION["SESS_mball_0"]}) + (SELECT SUM(mball_i) FROM pr WHERE mball_0 = 
    {$_SESSION["SESS_mball_0"]})) AS theSum");
```

And if `$_SESSION["SESS_mball_0"]` is a string, you need to put quotes around it. There's also no need for nested selects.

If it's a string, you should also escape it in case there are special characters.

```
$mball_0 = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["SESS_mball_0"]);
$res = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(mball_h) + SUM(mball_i) AS theSum
                    FROM pr
                    WHERE mball_0 = '$mball_0'");
```

It would be better if you upgraded to mysqli or PDO and used parametrized queries instead of substituting variables directly into SQL.